# Android Image decoding from base64 to bitmap returns null . while its is working fine in my other test app .

Tags: android, listview, bitmap

Im encoding profile picture (BitMap) to base64 String and sending it to PHP server(mysql) , but when i retrieve it to display in LIstView , its not working .

**My Class to Encode and Decode Image .**

```
public class ImageEncoder {

    public ImageEncoder()
    {

    }
     public  String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap){
         ByteArrayOutputStream ByteStream=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
         bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, ByteStream);
         byte [] b=ByteStream.toByteArray();
         String temp=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
         return temp;
   }

      public  Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString){
             try{
               byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(encodedString,Base64.DEFAULT);
               Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
               return bitmap;
             }catch(Exception e){
               e.getMessage();
               return null;
             }
              }

}
```

**My CustomListAdapter to Show listView**

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Context context;
    private final String[] itemname;
    private final String[] imgid;
    String my="";
    ImageEncoder obj = new ImageEncoder();
    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, String[] itemname, String[] imgid) {
        super(context, R.layout.mylist, itemname);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.context=context;
        this.itemname=itemname;
        this.imgid=imgid;
    }

    public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
        my=imgid[position];
        Bitmap myy= obj.StringToBitMap(my);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(myy);
        extratxt.setText("Description "+itemname[position]);
        return rowView;

    };

}
```

i tried encoding and decoding in seprate test app , its working fine there . I tried everything but found no problem . i debugged the whole app , there is String in Array but its not decoding into bitmap ,
 `Bitmap myy= obj.StringToBitMap(my);` my contains String but myy is still null .

Comment: it would be easier if you return url of the image when retrieving from the server, it would save you the decoding part. and for more convenience you can use picasso or glide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Upload your image and store it into your server and store the image url into your database.For uploading the image use following code

```
public void UploadFile() {
    try {

        // Set your file path into imagepath
        FileInputStream fstrm = new FileInputStream(imagepath);

        String[] urlSplit = imagepath.split("/");
        String fileName = urlSplit[urlSplit.length - 1];

        // Set your server page url (and the file title/description)
        HttpFileUpload hfu = new HttpFileUpload("User Domain name/file_upload.php", "my file title", "my file description", fileName);

        upflag = hfu.Send_Now(fstrm);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // Error: File not found
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



import android.util.Log;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class HttpFileUpload implements Runnable {
    URL connectURL;
    String responseString;
    String Title;
    String fileName;
    String Description;
    byte[ ] dataToServer;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

    public HttpFileUpload(String urlString, String vTitle, String vDesc, String file){
            try{
                    connectURL = new URL(urlString);
                    Title= vTitle;
                    Description = vDesc;
                    fileName = file;
            }catch(Exception ex){
                Log.i("HttpFileUpload", "URL Malformatted");
            }
    }

    public Boolean Send_Now(FileInputStream fStream){
            fileInputStream = fStream;
            return Sending();
    }

    Boolean Sending(){

        System.out.println("file Name is :"+fileName);

            String iFileName = fileName;
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            String Tag="fSnd";
            try
            {
                    Log.e(Tag, "Starting Http File Sending to URL");

                    // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)connectURL.openConnection();

                    // Allow Inputs
                    conn.setDoInput(true);

                    // Allow Outputs
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);

                    // Don't use a cached copy.
                    conn.setUseCaches(false);

                    // Use a post method.
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

                    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\""+ lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(Title);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"description\""+ lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(Description);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + iFileName +"\"" + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    Log.e(Tag, "Headers are written");

                    // create a buffer of maximum size
                    int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                    int maxBufferSize = 1024;
                    int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    byte[ ] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                    // read file and write it into form...
                    int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    while (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0,bufferSize);
                    }
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                    // close streams
                    fileInputStream.close();

                    dos.flush();

                    Log.e(Tag, "File Sent, Response: " + String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));

                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                    // retrieve the response from server
                    int ch;

                    StringBuffer b =new StringBuffer();
                    while( ( ch = is.read() ) != -1 ){ b.append( (char)ch ); }
                    String s=b.toString();
                    Log.i("Response", s);
                    dos.close();

                        if(String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()).equals("200"))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException ex)
            {
                    Log.e(Tag, "URL error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }

            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                    Log.e(Tag, "IO error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
            }
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    }
}
```

And after that when you want this image at that time get image url from server side and convert it into Bitmap by using following code snippet.

```
public static Bitmap convrtUrltoBitmap(String src) {
try {
    URL url = new URL(src);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    return myBitmap;
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Log exception
    return null;
}
}
```

And use this bitmap to display image.

Comment: its confusing . the uploading part .

Comment: You have your image path then only  you have to pass your image uri to above method i.e. variable imagepath contain your image uri